# Equivalent to Functor or Foldable for higher-kinded types

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types

Consider this code, using the `Functor` and `Foldable` typeclasses:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable #-}

data Foo a = Foo (Maybe a) [a] deriving(Show, Functor, Foldable)

fmap (+1) (Foo (Just 1) [2,3,4]) -- result: Foo (Just 2) [3,4,5]
sum (Foo (Just 1) [2,3,4]) -- result: 10
```

Is there some analogous set of typeclasses that can operate on higher-kinded type parameters? For example:

```
data Bar a = Bar (a Int) (a Bool)

somethingLikeFmap :: forall t f g. SomethingLikeFunctor t => (forall a. f a -> g a) -> t f -> t g

somethingLikeAll :: forall t f. SomethingLikeFoldable t => (forall a. f a -> Bool) -> t f -> Bool

somethingLikeFmap listToMaybe (Bar [1,2,3] [False, True]) -- desired result: Bar (Just 1) (Just False)
somethingLikeAll null (Bar [1,2,3] [False, True]) -- desired result: False
somethingLikeAll null (Bar [] []) -- desired result: True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for [`rank2classes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes). For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, StandaloneDeriving, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Rank2
import qualified Rank2.TH

data Bar a = Bar (a Int) (a Bool)
deriving instance Show (Bar Maybe)
Rank2.TH.deriveFunctor ''Bar
Rank2.TH.deriveFoldable ''Bar

main = do
    print $ Rank2.fmap listToMaybe (Bar [1,2,3] [False, True])
    print $ getAll (Rank2.foldMap (All . null) (Bar [1,2,3] [False, True]))
    print $ getAll (Rank2.foldMap (All . null) (Bar [] []))
```

**EDIT:** Or possibly [`mmorph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.2), though I suspect `rank2classes` may prove more useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica!

Comment: Yet another flavor, with different kinds: [conkin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conkin-1.0.2/docs/Conkin.html).

Comment: @dfeuer I think that's worth an answer of its own.

Comment: `TaversableB` from barbies http://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Barbie.html#t:TraversableB supports a `bfoldMap` function http://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-2.0.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Barbie.html#v:bfoldMap

Comment: [`Rank2.Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.4.1/docs/Rank2.html#t:Functor) is an instance of [`FunctorOf (~>) (->)`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eoo16m/base_category_polymorphic_functor_and_functorof/).